# Why is execEmbeddedViewsAction called a few times?

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I have a virtual scroll in my app that emits a slice of a big array and then I iterate through those items with *ngFor to display a list of `li` items that inside have quite a lot of code. Based on the current element from the array it decides which buttons and components inside `li` to show. Of course, when I scroll down - a new slice of the array is emitted, so all the bindings are changed and each `li` element and its inner parts are getting new data, so change detection takes them all into account.

The problem is that it's lagging a little bit when I scroll down. Performance tab of the Chrome shows that it takes more than 300ms to run change detection for every elment in the list, and I noticed that `execEmbeddedViewsAction` is called a few times during those 300ms. Please take a look.
[image: performance tab screenshot]

Why does it happen so many times? What are the possible solutions to my problem? Is it worth to encapsulate all the bindings to different components inside `li` into one single object, so that those components will have only one `@Input` binding?